# Plotly does not display LaTeX formulas after implementing $...$

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

This is an example from plotly website: [Latex in Python](https://plotly.com/python/LaTeX/), and different from the example, my code just won't show the rendered formula:

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.line(x=[1, 2, 3, 4], y=[1, 4, 9, 16], title=r'$\alpha_{1c} = 352 \pm 11 \text{ km s}^{-1}$')
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis_title=r'$\sqrt{(n_\text{c}(t|{T_\text{early}}))}$',
    yaxis_title=r'$d, r \text{ (solar radius)}$'
)
fig.show()
```

My result:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Latex in y-axis title in plotly not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66713595/latex-in-y-axis-title-in-plotly-not-working)

Comment: Tried just now, it doesn't work on Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Jupyter notebook on Chrome and Edge, nor VSCode Jupyter notebook. A strange problem. @AndreVale69

Comment: Try running it in Colab in the server environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a workaround posted in the plotly git issues:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/8131#issuecomment-1589961116

This works for me in Jupyter-lab